# Detecting if FIPS is being enforced via .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, fips

Is there a way to determine from the .NET framework whether or not the FIPS policy is being enforced on the windows computer?

Comment: Check the Registry value at `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy\Enabled`?

Comment: FWIW If you're dealing with FIPS enforcing certain classes be used in .NET, [.NET 4.8](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/28/announcing-net-framework-4-8-early-access-build-3694/) fixes this: *the SHA256Managed class (and the other managed cryptography classes) will redirect the cryptographic operations to a system cryptography library.*

Comment: Otherwise this might do https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/cryptoconfig.cs,60dba5f3579c03b5

Comment: @ta.speot.is If I interpret your .Net4.8 link correctly, it no longer matters whether we use AESManaged, and SHA256Managed or not as the system will now automatically choose the FIPS variant on a FIPS system, and the normal variant on a normal system. - Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to check whether FIPS is enabled or not:

```
public static object getKey(string Name)
{
    RegistryKey uac = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy", true);
    if (uac == null)
    {
        uac = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy");
    }
    return uac.GetValue(Name);
}
```

Just pass "Enabled" key into it and it will return 1 or 0 based on the enabled or disabled.

Comment: You might not want to create that key if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah its fine we can remove the if condition if user don't want to create the key.

Answer (score 5):

It has already been answered by @ta-speot-is in the comments, adding it as an answer if someone overlooks that comment.

To know if FIPS is enabled we can simply check the boolean flag `CryptoConfig.AllowOnlyFipsAlgorithms` available in .Net Framework 4.0 and higher versions.